# How to find class variable with string selected from DropDown

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class Tv with some variables, which are string. 
On the page I have DropDown list. I need user to select option from DropDown list and enter the value. And this value must be saved to Tv class variable, which has name like selected string.
Later I pass Tv object to my BackEnd.

My Tv class

```
export class Tv  {
 id: number;
 brand: string;
 model: string;
 color:string;
 display_technology:string;
 screen_size:string;
 refresh_rate:string;
 weight:string;
 condition:string;
 inputs:string;
}
```

My DropDown list

```
<select class="form-control col-md-3">
    <option *ngFor="let param of parameters">{{param}}</option>
  </select>
  <div class="col">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="paramer" required>
  </div>
```

**UPD** Working version.

```
<div class="row">
  <select name="tvParam" class="form-control col-md-3" [(ngModel)]="selectedParam">
    <option *ngFor="let param of parametrs">{{param}}</option>
  </select>
  <div class="col">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tvParamValue" [(ngModel)] = "paramet" (change)="passData()">
  </div>


passData(){
 this.tv[this.selectedParam.toLocaleLowerCase()] = this.paramet;
}
```

Comment: Did my solution work? @Vitalii Pshenychniuk

Comment: Thank you very much! @SebaCherian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a variable tvVar of class Tv

```
tvVar: Tv;
```

You can set the value by

```
tvVar[paramSelected] = valueEnteredInInput;
```